# Dictionary to List of Keys on Conditional Match

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, type-conversion

Say I have this dictionary:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Location> connections;
```

I want to get a list of the keys from this dictionary that match some conditions on their values. For example, this works for me:

```
List<string> users = connections.Where(x.Value.IsNearby(anotherLocation)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value).Keys.ToList();
```

But this is nasty because it goes from a dictionary to sub-dictionary, to a list of keys. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you've got the `ToDictionary` call at all. You just need a `Select` call:

```
List<string> users = connections.Where(x => x.Value.IsNearby(anotherLocation)
                                .Select(x => x.Key)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Been a long weekend, mate. Not everyday my brain works right :) Thanks, Jon!